# How do I check if one table data is being referred in other processes

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

How do I check if one table data is being referred in other processes / procedure / is being used in other tables in sybase?

Comment: You may want to clarify your question and possibly provide some examples.

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Comment: this is in sybase-ase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.xtype
    FROM dbo.syscomments c
    INNER JOIN dbo.sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
    WHERE c.TEXT LIKE 'Table_Name_here' 
   -- and xtype = 'P' --un-comment if you want only procedures
```

Comment: this can help me .. i was unnecessarily banging my head trying to figure out the solution wrt to the column data (my column has specific type of data).. thanks !